# ActionScript 3 use multiple onKeyDown/onKeyUP

Tags: actionscript-3

Im trying to get a two plyer version of Snake running but i am having trouble getting the second snake to work, player 1 plays with w,a,s and d while player 2 uses the arrow keys. Player 1 with w,a,s and d is working player 2 with the arrows does not.

The code looks like this:

```
    function onKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
        if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.A){
           SnakeDirection = "left";
        }else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.D) {
           SnakeDirection = "right";
        }else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.W) {
            SnakeDirection = "up";
        }else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.S) {
            SnakeDirection = "down";
        }
    }
    function onKeyUp(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
        if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.A) {
            SnakeDirection = "";
        }else if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.D) {
            SnakeDirection = "";
        }else if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.W ) {
            SnakeDirection = "";
        }else if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.S){
            SnakeDirection = "";
        }
    }
/*      function onKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
            if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){
               Snake2Direction = "left";
            }else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT) {
               Snake2Direction = "right";
            }else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP) {
                Snake2Direction = "up";
            }else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN) {
                Snake2Direction = "down";
            }
        }
        function onKeyUp(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
            if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT) {
                Snake2Direction = "";
            }else if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT) {
                Snake2Direction = "";
            }else if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP ) {
                Snake2Direction = "";
            }else if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN){
                Snake2Direction = "";
            }
        }*/
```

The comments are there because it breaks the game, from my understanding the errors are because i can only use one onKeyUp/Down. If that is the case, is there another way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use 2 functions for each event? Wouldn't it be much simpler if you just did the logic for the second player in the same function that also handles the logic of the first player?

Like this:

```
function onKeyDown(event : KeyboardEvent) : void {
        //handle player 1
        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.A) {
            SnakeDirection = "left";
        } else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.D) {
            SnakeDirection = "right";
        } else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.W) {
            SnakeDirection = "up";
        } else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.S) {
            SnakeDirection = "down";
        }
        //handle player 2
        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT) {
            Snake2Direction = "left";
        } else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT) {
            Snake2Direction = "right";
        } else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP) {
            Snake2Direction = "up";
        } else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN) {
            Snake2Direction = "down";
        }
    }

    function onKeyUp(event : KeyboardEvent) : void {
        //handle player 1
        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.A || event.keyCode == Keyboard.D || event.keyCode == Keyboard.W || event.keyCode == Keyboard.S) {
            SnakeDirection = "";
        }
        //handle player 2
        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT ||event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT || event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP || event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN) {
            Snake2Direction = "";
        }
    }
```

Keep in mind, you want to keep the if-blocks for the players separated, so that you can get multiple inputs at the same time.

Also as a side note, the else-if blocks in your `onKeyUp` function are unnecessary. They all do the same thing anyway.

Comment: That never crossed my mind to use the same function, thanks! I'll give it a try in the morning!